# On Finitely generated prime ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let R be a commutative ring with unity and P be a prime ideal of R such that P is finitely generated. Let I be an ideal of R such that I is contained in P. 
Is I also finitely generated?

I think the answer is NO : ( I tried to prove the statement but fails to do that is why I think the answer is no)

Comment: Hint: $R = \mathbb{Q}\left[x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots\right]$, $P = \left(x_1\right)$ and $I = \left(x_1 x_2, x_1 x_3, x_1 x_4, \ldots\right)$. (Use gradedness to show that $I$ is not finitely generated.)